# Custom AutoField Integer Sequence in Django

Tags: django

I have Django with default IDs, and I want to distribute the system **without use of random UUIDs**.

I take that in my use case, the number of servers won't exceed a N=1000, so, I'd like to reserve IDs sub-sequences to each server, so that:

- SERVER 1 would have IDs 1001, 2001, 3001,...
- SERVER 2 would have IDs 1002, 2002, 3002, etc.

I'd like to do that globally, including all models, even Django system models, so I've defined a function to get the last ID of the subsequence, like:

```py
# Used to split primary key spaces.
SERVER_ID = int(os.getenv('SERVER_ID', 1))

# Function to compute different next primary key for each server:
def DB_NEXT_PK(Model):
    ID_LENGTH = 3
    FACTOR_10 = 10**ID_LENGTH

    last = Model.objects.filter(id__endswith=f'%.{ID_LENGTH}d' % SERVER_ID).last()

    if last is not None:
        return ((last.pk // FACTOR_10) + 1) * FACTOR_10 + SERVER_ID
    else:
        return FACTOR_10 + SERVER_ID
```

So, suppose I want to use such or equivalent function for the IDs. How would I have to override the `django.db.fields.AutoField` to properly do this? I found the latest Django 3.2, [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.2/#s-customizing-type-of-auto-created-primary-keys) has an option to customize AutoField, but I don't quite get how it is best to do to accomplish this.

I'm currently looking into making migrations that provide this function as default value for id fields, but I think this is not the optimal solution. So, what are your thoughts on it? Thanks!

**Note:** I'm not using central database and connecting Django instances to it, consider that each Django runs with its local Database, and use some sort of post-signals to synchronize with other instances.

Comment: When you say `server 1`, `server 2`, etc are you talking about database servers?

Comment: Yes, database servers. Basically, each Django instance with its own database, and I'm considering synchronizing them through global post-signals, though maybe there's a better way, but you can imagine it like that. I'm not using any JS clients, just basic Django.

Comment: Django does not distribute the ids as far as I know, you will need to look to the database backend. For PostgreSQL you can alter the sequence, some databases might not offer this.

Comment: Thanks, Willem, I've created a related question: [How to globally redefine **nextval** in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66344119/how-to-globally-redefine-nextval-in-postgresql).

Comment: If you want to run different database servers, you can write a custom db router, though I've never needed to do this. Docs on this are here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/multi-db/