# How to globally redefine nextval in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

The `nextval` computes the next value by adding `1` to the previous value `i` in the `some_id_seq`:

`nextval = i + 1`.

But I want the `nextval` increment primary keys for all tables based on the server ID `N` in environment variable `export SERVER_ID=N`, by rule:

`nextval = (i // 1000 + 1) * 1000 + N`,

producing sequence that always ends with a few zeros-padded server `N`'s ID, like so, if `SERVER_ID=3`:

`1003, 2003, 3003, 4003, 5003, 6003, 7003, 8003, 9003, 10003, ...`.

Is there a way to globally redefine the `nextval` function in PostgreSQL, on a per-server basis?

**Related answer:** [Primary key with randomly varying increments](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71702/primary-key-with-randomly-varying-increments-so-it-cannot-be-guessed-easily/71719#71719).

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to what you think, the increment doesn't have to be `1`. You can define the increment and the start value when defining a sequence. So you can start with `1003` and increment by `1000`.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ecneuqes
                INCREMENT BY 1000
                START WITH 1003;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=03635f43899028079b2f9e2c15d24526)

Comment: :) So you suggest redefining SEQUENCE instead of `nextval`. Not exactly what I asked, but achieves similar effect in this case. A few things that concern me: (1) that these sequence definitions are part of the data, not the db setting, makes db dumps different on different servers, (2) that it is not as flexible as recursive function: what if I want my IDs be growing by `nextval = i + randint(1,5)` or other variants?

Comment: @MindeyI. If you dump a database, the increment and start with values will also be dumped and thus restored in to the same settings in the target database.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular sequence that increments by one and do the calculation after you retrieved the value. You cannot get at an environment variable unless you write a C, Perl or Python function, but you could put the server number into a configuration table.